# What guarantees that joint diagonalization is possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

According to the Wikipedia article on the [common spatial pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_spatial_pattern) algorithm, one can find the following matrices by joint diagonalization of a pair of covariance matrices $R_1$ and $R_2$:

$$
P = [\mathbf{p_1}, \cdots , \mathbf{p_n}]
$$
$$
D = \mbox{diag} \{\lambda_1, \cdots ,\lambda_n\}
$$

such that $\mathbf{P^{-1}R_1P=D}$ and $\mathbf{P^{-1}R_2P=I_n}$, where $\mathbf{I_n}$ is the identity matrix of rank $n$.

Now, I know that there are "plenty" of non-diagonalizable matrices, so I'm inclined to wonder what guarantees the above is possible, and when.

Comment: I read the article and I'm baffled too... Isn't $P^{-1}R_2P = I$ the same as $R_2 = I$?

Comment: Well, if it _is_ jointly diagonalizable in that fashion, all of that is consistent.

Comment: Then I'd say it is jointly diagonalizable if $R_2 = I$, and you only need to diagonalize $R_1$ because no matter what $P$ and $D$ are, $P^{-1}R_2P = I$ is guaranteed. I feel that the Wikipedia page you're referring to is not very reliable.

Comment: Well, are there any non-scalar multiples of $I$ that work?

Comment: If $P^{-1}R_2P$ is diagonal, it must contain eigenvalues of $R_2$, so you at least require $R_2$ to have only one distinct eigenvalue.

Comment: I concur with Tunococ. The Wikipedia article you cited does not sound right. If $P^{-1}R_2P=I_n$, then $R_2$ is necessarily equal to $I_n$, but by assumption, $R_2$ is just an arbitrary covariance matrix. In general, it is *not* the identity matrix.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the second opinion. I'll dig it up myself and correct it in an answer.

Comment: In general, two square matrices $\,A,B\,$ are simultaneously diagonalizable (which seems to be more or less the same as jointly diagonalizable) iff there are diagonalizable **and** $\,AB=BA\,$ ...

Answer (score 4):

The most likely explanation is that they are referring to joint approximate diagonalization by an orthogonal matrix the minimizes the sum of the Frobenius norm of the off-diagonal terms.  The algorithm used is often called JADE and a quick web search for JADE and common spatial pattern picks up many promising hits.